# Custom Route Not Matched

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

In routeConfig i have code:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Contact", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Custom",
                url: "Secret/Routes/1",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

I have created Custom Route as:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Custom",
                    url: "Secret/Routes/1",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
```

But when i am giving direct link as:

```
http://localhost:4618/Secret/Routes/1
```

Its not rendering to Account Controller's Login Action.

Please help me. Where i am making mistake in route???

Want to render to Account Controller Login Action when 
URL is

```
http://localhost:4618/Secret/Routes/1
```

Comment: Put your custom route before the default route (the order or routes is important)

Comment: Routing works in order (of registration). The first route that matches will be used. "/Secret/Routes/1" matches your default route (as in "controller = Secret, action = Routes and id = 1).

Comment: Thank you both of you.. was unaware that routing works in order. Solved my issue... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When routing handles URL requests, it tries to match the URL of the request to a route. Matching a URL request to a route depends on all the following conditions:

- The route patterns that you have defined or the default route
  patterns, if any, that are included in your project type.
- The order in which you added them to the Routes collection.
- Any default values that you have provided for a route.
- Any constraints that you have provided for a route.
- Whether you have defined routing to handle requests that match a
  physical file.

More info about [ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx).

You have to change order of routes.

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Custom",
            url: "Secret/Routes/1",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Contact", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```